# Как сделать так, чтобы только часть кода была доступна в другом файле?

Tags: python

Создадим файл test.py и напишем в его этот код:

```
x = 123
def f(a):
    global x
    return a + x
```

Как сделать так, чтобы в условном файле test2.py был доступ только к функции `f()`, но при этом при её вызове не должна выводиться ошибка, что переменной `x` не существует?

Comment: Как в файле `test2.py` оказывается доступна функция `f`?

Comment: Импортируйте в test2.py ```from test import x, f``` и дальше можете проверить ```print(f(2))```

Comment: Stanislav Volodarskiy, я же говорю, переменная `x` не должна быть доступна.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дополню ответы третьим способом. Также импортировать функцию как и ранее, но с одним нюансом - избавиться от глобалки, а x указать в параметрах функции в качестве значения по умолчанию:

```
def f(a, x = 123):
```

В таком случае x можно будет при вызове функции указать вторым аргументом. При передаче одного аргумента, в вызов функции f(), переменная x будет использовать значение по умолчанию, указанное в голове (инициализации) функции.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло! А как так сделать с классами?

Answer (score 0):

1. Оба файла должны быть в 1 директории
2. Импортируйте test в test2

```
from test import x, f
```

Либо (чтобы сразу всё импортировать)

```
from test import *
```

Готово.